# How to parse XML into Javascript having same name for node?

Tags: javascript

In a scenario I am getting this XML response, and I need to parse it to use it further.

Response XML:

```
<array>
<data>
<value>200</value>
<value>Success</value>
</data>
</array>
```

So, how to get values of this XML into a variable?

I want result like this:

```
var code = 200;
var message = Success;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code bellow :

```js
var xmlString = "<array><data><value>200</value><value>Success</value></data></array>"

if (window.DOMParser){
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
 {
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(xmlString);
}
console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName("value"));
var code = xml.getElementsByTagName("value")[0].textContent;
var message = xml.getElementsByTagName("value")[1].textContent;

alert("code :"+code+"\nmessage :"+message);
```

Comment: does it help ?.